# How to retrieve value of cons cell by key name?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Say I have a list of cons cells like so:

```
(setq foo '(("a" . 1) ("b" . 2) ("c" . 3)))
```

And I'd like to retrieve the value of a particular cons cell by "key name". Is there a function that will let me do this?

E.g.

```
(get-by-key "a" foo) ;; => 1
```

Or something similar. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Such list is called an *association list*, or *alist* for short. Formally, an association list is a list of conses of a key and its associated value.

The `assoc` function is what you are looking for. It takes a key and an alist as its arguments and returns the first association for the key in the alist in terms of [`equal`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Equality-Predicates.html#index-equal-127):

```lisp
ELISP> (setq foo '(("a" . 1) ("b" . 2) ("c" . 3)))
(("a" . 1)
 ("b" . 2)
 ("c" . 3))

ELISP> (assoc "a" foo)
("a" . 1)

ELISP> (cdr (assoc "a" foo))
1
```

The `assoc-string` function is similar to the `assoc` function but specific to association lists whose keys are strings. In addition to a key and an alist, it can take another optional argument that makes the key comparison case-insensitive:

```
ELISP> (assoc-string "a" foo)
("a" . 1)

ELISP> (assoc-string "A" foo)
nil

ELISP> (assoc-string "A" foo t)
("a" . 1)
```

For the full list of association list-related functions, refer to [GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Association-Lists.html).

Answer (score 3):

[assoc-default](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Association-Lists.html#index-assoc_002ddefault-429) lets you retrieve the value of a particular cons cell by "key name".

```
ELISP> (setq foo '(("a" . 1) ("b" . 2) ("c" . 3)))
(("a" . 1)
 ("b" . 2)
 ("c" . 3))

ELISP> (assoc-default "a" foo)
1
```

Answer (score 2):

[`alist-get`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Association-Lists.html#index-alist_002dget) with the KEY and the ALIST as arguments gives you VALUE associated to the KEY.
E.g.,

```el
(alist-get 'a '((a . 1) (b . 2) (c . 3)))
```

evaluates to 1.

Comparison is done with `eq` by default. But its full argument list is:

```el
(alist-get KEY ALIST &optional DEFAULT REMOVE TESTFN)
```

So one can give:

1. A DEFAULT value that is returned if there is no match for KEY,
2. A flag REMOVE that removes the KEY VALUE pair if the new value is DEFAULT in

```el
(setf (alist-get KEY ALIST DEFAULT t) DEFAULT)
```

3. A test function `TESTFN` for comparing KEY with the cars of ALIST